# Jacoco shows coverage 0.0 when running the gradle task but shows correct when run from Intellij

Tags: jacoco

I am using Jacoco plugin to calculate the code coverage for spring boot application. The Jacoco configuration from the build.gradle looks like this:

```
jacocoTestReport {
reports {
    xml.enabled false
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
}

afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it,
                exclude: ['**/models/**',
                          '**/config/**',
                          '**/constants/**',
                          '**/Application.class'])
    })
}
```

}

and

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
violationRules {
    rule {
        element = 'PACKAGE'
        excludes = ['some packages']
        limit {
            counter = 'BRANCH'
            minimum = 0.7
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run the coverage from the IntelliJ then it shows the correct result but when I run it with `gradlew clean buils`, it fails with coverage 0.0.
[image]

I have written an example class and here are the jacoco report snapshots-
report: [image]
class:[image]
And the test I wrote for the SomeClass is

```
public class SomeClassTest {
private SomeClass someClass;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    someClass = new SomeClass(12, 23);
}

@Test
public void shouldSumTwoValues() {
    assertThat(someClass.sum()).isEqualTo(35);
}
```

}

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Given `src/main/java/SomeClass.java`

```
class SomeClass {

  private Integer value1;
  private Integer value2;

  SomeClass(Integer value1, Integer value2) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
  }

  Integer sum() {
    return value1 + value2;
  }

}
```

`src/test/java/SomeClassTest.java`

```
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class SomeClassTest {
  private SomeClass someClass;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    someClass = new SomeClass(12, 23);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldSumTwoValues() {
    assertEquals(35, (int) someClass.sum());
  }
}
```

and `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

dependencies {
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

execution of `gradle test jacocoTestReport` produces following report in `build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html`

[image: report]

Addition to `build.gradle` of

```
jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
    xml.enabled false
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
  }

  afterEvaluate {
    classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
        fileTree(dir: it,
                exclude: ['**/models/**',
                          '**/config/**',
                          '**/constants/**',
                          '**/Application.class'])
    })
  }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
  violationRules {
    rule {
        element = 'PACKAGE'
        excludes = ['some packages']
        limit {
            counter = 'BRANCH'
            minimum = 0.7
        }
    }
  }
}
```

doesn't change result/report, except of change of directory with report on `build/jacocoHtml`.

Comment: @PoojaGurav usage of wrapper (`gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.10 && ./gradlew clean test jacocoTestReport`) doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I discovered that it is due to the fact that I set minimum = 1. When I change it to 0.9 all of the sudden it works